# Creating a SimpleForm for a Decorator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I've got a message class that you can send to a user.  Until recently, it could only be sent to a single user, but not the requirement is to send to multiple users.  I decided to wrap message in a MessageProxy (really a Decorator, but that word was already taken by Draper).

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :priority_type
end

class MessageProxy
  def initialize(args = {})
    @message = Message.new(args)
  end
  def method_missing(method_sym, *arguments, &block)
    @message.send(method_sym, *arguments, &block)
  end
end
```

I tried to use the message proxy in a form, but I get `Association :priority_type not found`.  This is especially odd because from my rails console, MessageProxy behaves as expected:

```
MessageProxy.new.priority_type # => nil instead of an exception
```

<strike>Why isn't my proxy forwarding the association methods to the message object?</strike>

I have looked into the SimpleForm source code and found that the issue is
in `SimpleForm::FormBuilder.find_association_reflection(association)`. It looks at `@object.class` but since @object is my decorator, not the delegatee, it can't find the association.

If I override `.class` so that it quacks like a Message, then when I try to call `MessageProxy.new.valid?` I also fire the Message validators.

Answer (score 0):

From the [code](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/749c926140ee383e8249f15d1846f5287c5a4c46/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L175-L192) and without seeing your view code, the only thing I can suggest is that instead of just using `f.association :priority_type` and letting SimpleForm infer the rest, you should pass a block to avoid the `SimpleForm::FormBuilder.find_association_reflection(association)` check like so:

```
f.association :priority_type do |p|
  p.input :something
end
```

Relevant part of SimpleForm::FormBuilder:

```
def association(association, options = {}, &block)
  options = options.dup

  return simple_fields_for(*[association,
    options.delete(:collection), options].compact, &block) if block_given?
  ...
end
```

as you can see passing a block will cause it to return before reaching the offending method.

Worth a try at least?